# Why does my object scale in the wrong direction?

Tags: transforms

[image: Look at the Transform menu, specifically at the Scale section.]

Hi i started working in Blender very recently. When i try to scale my object using the Transform menu on the right it scales in the wrong direction. Actually all transformations withing the menu work in wrong directions. It works fine when i use shortcut tools as 'G', 'S' and 'R' but when i try to use transformations in this menu they go in wrong directions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the mesh in object mode and press Ctrl A > Apply Rotation and scale. In this way the mesh remains the same, but its transform values become xyz 000 111, which is the "default" values that every mesh should have for avoiding odd behaviours.

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem!

Comment: Applying transformations are destructive. There is a reason blender works this way. You should not use apply like this in your workflow, if the only reason is that you dont yet master the interface.

Comment: I disagree, applying transformations should always be performed before going forward with the work, expecially whith uneven scale values, which bring unexpected behaviours on many situations (i.e. many modifiers will misbehave).

Comment: I think, depending on the situation, you are both right. If the model is in the *rest position*, as in the screenshot, the transformation should be applied. On the other hand, if the model is in a *pose* (e.g. the clock has been hit & has fallen down), then applying the transformation is a bad idea, especially if the only reason is that the UI tools are not working as expected. Note that most tools have options to change things like [transform orientation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.6/editors/3dview/controls/orientation.html), pivot point, etc. which can help in this situation.